# Exclude elements of one array from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to exclude elements of the array `$tempobjects` from the array `$objects`. What is the quickest way to do this?

```
$objects = new MyObjects();
$tempobjects = new MyObjects();

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  $objects->addObject(new MyObject(...));
}

//...fill $tempobjects with some temporary data

$tempobjects = $objects - $tempobjects; // HOW TO DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS?
```

Comment: Looks like $objects and $tempObjects are objects (or objects that comprise a collection of data) rather than arrays

Comment: `array_diff` or `array_diff_assoc` are the usual ways to do this for arrays, but as mark baker said, you have objects, so those functions probably won't work. try converting your objects to arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: remove duplicate items in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036403/php-remove-duplicate-items-in-an-array)

Comment: @sgroves do you know if it would work if both of the objects in question implemented the ArrayAccess Interface?

Comment: @Anigel, in this case is not an array... Maybe he will need to add a method on the class that does this for him.

Comment: @orangepill they might, but i'm not sure. i doubt it.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Indeed you are correct, I made the mistake of looking at what was asked rather than what the code said.

Comment: @sgroves just confirmed you where right... gives a warning "Argument #1 in not an array" :(

Comment: try typecasting your objects to arrays, e.g. `$new_objects = (array) $objects;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** `$tempobjects` and `$objects` were arrays (like your title mentions), which based on your sample code they are **not**, you could exclude elements using functions **[array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)** (for comparing values) or **[array_diff_key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php)** (for comparing keys).

See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/eyWuKt)**.