# How can I remove duplicate values from an array in PHP?

Tags: php

```
array=[{"abc":"qwe","sdsd":"ewewe","fff":"gggg"},

{"poi":"ytr","wert":"yui","iuyy":"yes"},

{"abc":"qwe","sdsd":"ewewe","fff":"gggg"},

{"poi":"ytr","wert":"yui","iuyy":"yes"},

{"abc":"qwe","sdsd":"ewewe","fff":"gggg"},

{"poi":"ytr","wert":"yui","iuyy":"yes"},

{"abc":"qwe","sdsd":"ewewe","fff":"gggg"}]
```

the output will be:

```
array=[{"abc":"qwe","sdsd":"ewewe","fff":"gggg"},

{"poi":"ytr","wert":"yui","iuyy":"yes"}]
```

Please help me to solve the question
If I am trying

this code

```
    <?php

    $array=[{"abc":"qwe","sdsd":"ewewe","fff":"gggg"},

    {"poi":"ytr","wert":"yui","iuyy":"yes"},

    {"abc":"qwe","sdsd":"ewewe","fff":"gggg"},

    {"poi":"ytr","wert":"yui","iuyy":"yes"},

    {"abc":"qwe","sdsd":"ewewe","fff":"gggg"},

    {"poi":"ytr","wert":"yui","iuyy":"yes"},

    {"abc":"qwe","sdsd":"ewewe","fff":"gggg"}];

    $array = array_unique($array);

    echo $array;

    ?>
```

then I am getting the run time error; while initializing please help I am getting this data from a very big existing function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: remove duplicate items in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036403/php-remove-duplicate-items-in-an-array)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from an array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307650/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

`array_unique()` sorts the values treated as string at first, then will keep the first key encountered for every value, and ignore all following keys. It does not mean that the key of the first related value from the unsorted array will be kept.

```
$getarray=json_decode(yourarray,true);

$array=array_unique($getarray);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use the array_unique function, it takes in an array and returns another array without duplicates.

Here is an example :

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your array initialization is wrong, Try this :

    <?php

$array=[["abc"=>"qwe","sdsd"=>"ewewe","fff"=>"gggg"],

    ["poi"=>"ytr","wert"=>"yui","iuyy"=>"yes"],

    ["abc"=>"qwe","sdsd"=>"ewewe","fff"=>"gggg"],

    ["poi"=>"ytr","wert"=>"yui","iuyy"=>"yes"],

    ["abc"=>"qwe","sdsd"=>"ewewe","fff"=>"gggg"],

    ["poi"=>"ytr","wert"=>"yui","iuyy"=>"yes"],

    ["abc"=>"qwe","sdsd"=>"ewewe","fff"=>"gggg"]

];
$unique=array(); 
$sorted_unique=array(); 
    for($n=0;$n<count($array);$n++) 
    { 
        $unique[]=serialize($array[$n]); 
    } 
    $array1=array_unique($unique); 
    for($n=0;$n<count($array1);$n++) 
    { 

            $sorted_unique[]=unserialize($array1[$n]); 

    } 
var_dump($sorted_unique);

?>
```